# How to add each hashmap to a arrayList

Tags: java, arrays

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (Response response : responseList) {
           if (responseList != null) {
               resultsMap.put("a", response.getResult());
               resultsMap.put("b",  response.getOriginalUrl())

              actualList.add(resultsMap);
}
```

This not adding to the hashMap to arrayList

Comment: Where do you declare/initialize `resultsMap`?

Comment: It is impossible for `responseList` to be `null` inside of the loop.

Comment: Please note that you are adding the same map object each time.

Comment: You are using the same instance of `resultsMap` each time in the loop (and add it repeatedly to the `actualList`).Only the last update will stick.

Comment: Can youe please tell me how to correct this?

Comment: First of all responseList is a array list? if yes you need to check it by  
`responseList.isEmpty()`

Comment: Add more details to your question please I will try help you

Answer (score 1):

In the given code

1. You are not initializing the hashmap in loop so the the a's and b's value will be override in hashmap in each iteration of responseList.
2. No use of checking responseList null in the loop so I removed it.

try this,

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = null;
for (Response response : responseList) {
            resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
               resultsMap.put("a", response.getResult());
               resultsMap.put("b",  response.getOriginalUrl())

              actualList.add(resultsMap);
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanations.

Comment: Now you deserve my +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @TobiasBrösamle

Answer (score 1):

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (Response response : responseList) { 
    if (response != null){
        Map resultsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        resultsMap.put("a", response.getResult()); 
        resultsMap.put("b", response.getOriginalUrl()) 
        actualList.add(resultsMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
if (responseList != null) {
    for (Response response : responseList) {
      HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
      map.put("a", response.getResult());
      map.put("b",  response.getOriginalUrl())
      actualList.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be more helpful with some explanations on why this works. The OP shall learn something, not just copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `HashMap` instance for each iteration of your loop.

Besides that, perhaps you meant to check that `response` is not null inside the loop, since `responseList` can't be null there.

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (Response response : responseList) {
    HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    if (response != null) {
        resultsMap.put("a", response.getResult());
        resultsMap.put("b",  response.getOriginalUrl())

        actualList.add(resultsMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like that :

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> actualList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (Response response : responseList) {
  HashMap<String,String>resultMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
           if (responseList != null) {
               resultsMap.put("a", response.getResult());
               resultsMap.put("b",  response.getOriginalUrl())
                }
      actualList.add(resultMap);        
}
```